# Cannot see data properties in object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I feel like I am missing something small, but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.  I have an ActionResult to receive some filters from a view.  I send them in json via ajax:

```
function filter() {
    var startDate = wijmo.Control.getControl('#StartDate').value;
    var endDate = wijmo.Control.getControl('#EndDate').value;
    var stringData = JSON.stringify({ 'StartDate': startDate, 'EndDate': endDate, 'SalesPersonId': '', 'Status': '', 'NewIncumbent': '' });
    $.ajax({ url: "@Url.Action("Filter")",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        contenttype: 'application/json',
        data: stringData,
        dataType: "json"
    });
};
```

I have a class to receive the data into:

```
 private class FilterResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("StartDate")]
        DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("EndDate")]
        DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("SalesPersonId")]
        int? SalesPersonId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Status")]
        int? Status { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("NewIncumbent")]
        bool? NewIncumbent { get; set; }
    }
```

The data is filled on entering the ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Filter(FilterResult results)
    {


    }
```

When I attempt to use results in any meaningful way, the only options are Equals, GetHashCode, GetType and ToString.

It makes me think the class is not being recognized, but in the Locals window I can see the data in results. FilterResults is in the same controller file.  Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: why is your filter class private? and so are the properties.. make the properties public if you want to see them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access level of your class members (properties) is `private` by default.  You would need to make the properties `public`:

```
private class FilterResult
{
    [JsonProperty("StartDate")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("EndDate")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("SalesPersonId")]
    public int? SalesPersonId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public int? Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("NewIncumbent")]
    public bool? NewIncumbent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the FilterResult class can be private if it's in the same controller as your ActionResult, but the properties have to be public if you want to be able to set them or access them from outside the class.  I would make the class and the properties public just to be sure

```
public class FilterResult
{
    [JsonProperty("StartDate")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("EndDate")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("SalesPersonId")]
    public int? SalesPersonId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public int? Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("NewIncumbent")]
    public bool? NewIncumbent { get; set; }
}
```